# Flags with different granularity in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, netezza

I'd like to say that I'm still learning how to use SQL so what I am asking might be very easy for some of you.

So, let's suppose that I have a column called SAMPLE, and one column called BATCH. Also, a BATCH contains a few SAMPLEs and for some reason there is a flag linked to the SAMPLE column (SAMPLE_FLG).

The BATLCH_FLG is there to show that at least one of the samples contained in that batch was flagged as 1.

You can visualize this scenario in this  [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTG3M.png)  or in the following table:

```
| sample      | batch | sample_flg | batch_flg |
|:-----------:|:-----:|:----------:|:---------:|
| A111 - 1000 | A11   |      0     |     0     |
| A111 - 200  | A11   |      0     |     0     |
| A111 - 500  | A11   |      0     |     0     |
| B234 - 700  | B234  |      0     |     0     |
| B234 - 50   | B234  |      1     |     1     |
| B234 - 75   | B234  |      0     |     0     |
| C567 - 100  | C567  |      1     |     1     |
| C567 - 700  | C567  |      1     |     0     |
| C567 - 500  | C567  |      0     |     0     |
```

How can I obtain with a SQL query just a single 1 for each batch in the BATCH_FLG column?
What I mean is that I shouldn't have 1 multiple times even if more than one sample for each batch is flagged as 1 (the last three rows in the example image).

The position of the 1 in the BATCH_FLG column is not important.

I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please include the expected result.

Comment: Also provide the structure of the tables and sample data

Comment: you can see an example in the picture. data and table look like that.  @NickW

Comment: the expected result is the BATCH_FLG column you can see in the example picture I posted @TheImpaler

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all information to your question as editable text

Comment: @NickW I'm sorry, I'm a new . Now I've added the table inside the question too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to produce the result you want. For example:

```
select t.*,
  case when row_number() over(patition by batch order by sample) = 1
       then 1 else 0 end as batch_flg
from t
```